How to represent a software's name in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts?
I am now trying to change the default shortcut Cmd+H to Cmd+M because it is difficult for me to reach the H key.

Then I try to set it in System Preferences > Keyboard  > Shortcuts. I can change the default Preferences... shortcut to Cmd+Shift+~. But there is a variable in the "Hide XXX". I think there is a special variable that can represent the application's name. But I don't know it.
